# How do I get the postal code from google map's autocomplete api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So my issue is that the results are spitting out as:

1980 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA, United States

...but I need it to give me the zipcode because when I put it back into google's Geocoder, for some reason it doesn't register the location.

// This is the code I have just the autocomplete input field

```
var input = document.getElementById('id_address');
var options = {
  types: ['address'],
  componentRestrictions: {country:'us'}
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

// This is how I'm using the geocoder

```
window.onload = function initMap() {
            console.log("{{ task.address }}");
            console.log("{{ location }}");
            var address = "{{ location }}";

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
                <!-- console.log(address); -->
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: results[0].geometry.location,
                    zoom: 12,
                  });
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                  });
              }


            });

        }
```

I have a working solution, but the user will have to input each piece of the address separately. I'm trying to change it so they can just fill out one input field and then I can spit that address into the gecoder.geocode().

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The [result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlaceResult) returned by the `autocomplete` contains an `address_components` array, one entry of which has the type 'postal_code', which for your sample address ("1980 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA, United States"), contains 94103.

**Note:** a city, county or state usually has more than one postal code, the only way to get a unique one would be to reverse geocode the returned coordinates, whether that is adequate will depend on the use.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/yst0tuxf/660/)

```js
function initialize() {
  var input = document.getElementById('id_address');
  var options = {
    types: ['address'],
    componentRestrictions: {
      country: 'us'
    }
  };
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
          document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;

        }
      }
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<input id="id_address" type="text" size="100" value="1980 Mission Street, San Francisco, CA, United States" />zip code:
<div id="postal_code"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.find()` function to search through the `address_components` array:

```
const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
const postalCode = place.address_components.find((component) => {
  return component.types.includes("postal_code");
});
console.log(postalCode);
```

Or make a function to get any `address_component`:

```
function getAddressComponent(component, place) {
  return place.address_components.find((component) => {
    return component.types.includes(component);
  });
}

const place = autocomplete.getPlace();
const postalCode = getAddressComponent("postal_code", place);
const city = getAddressComponent("locality", place);
const province = getAddressComponent("administrative_area_level_2", place);
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're using the Google Maps Geocoding API, the [Result](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Results) has the `address_components` array which contains the `postal_code`. You just need to specify the type as `postal_code`.

Comment: sorry if i wasn't clear. i'm using the Google Autocomplete API. When the data in the autocomplete input field is submitted, it doesn't spit out the "postal code". I need the "postal code" so that I can input it into Google's Geocoder().