# Google maps API - Retrieve only by postal code

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to put some restrictions to the Google Maps Autocomplete API.

I want it to retrieve and autocomplete the Postal Code only, nothing else, not even the country. But I am struggling filtering it. I am confused with the documentations for this process.

How can I resolve this issue ?

Here is the code :

**HTML**

```html
<form role="form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locality" name="locality" placeholder="Stadt oder PLZ" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```javascript
var localityInput = document.getElementById('locality');
var localityOptions = {
  types: ['(regions)'], #Retrieve postal code only
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'ch'}
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(localityInput, localityOptions);
```

---

**Update 1**

Here I'm trying link 2 differents javascript codes but I have no clue how I can do it.

**HTML**

```html
<form role="form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locality" name="locality" placeholder="Stadt oder PLZ" />
     <div id="postal_code"></div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```javascript
var localityInput = document.getElementById('locality');
var localityOptions = {
  types: ['address'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'ch'}
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(localityInput, localityOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
          document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;
        }
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: May this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487077/how-do-i-get-the-postal-code-from-google-maps-autocomplete-api

Comment: How can I merge both of these codes to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it thanks to 
[stackoverflow.com/questions/34487077/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34487077/)
here is the final code.

it only works if the postal code is in the search bar.

```
<form role="form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locality" name="locality" placeholder="Stadt oder PLZ" />
     <div id="postal_code"></div>
</form

<script>
var localityInput = document.getElementById('locality');
var localityOptions = {
  types: ['(regions)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'ch'}
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(localityInput, localityOptions);
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
        if (place.address_components[i].types[j] == "postal_code") {
          document.getElementById('postal_code').innerHTML = place.address_components[i].long_name;

        }
      }
    }
  })
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```